# How get ASCII of a string

Tags: c, unix, casting

i need to get the ascii (int and hex format) representation of a string char by char. For example if i have the string "hello", i would get for `int ascii 104 101 108 108 111`
and for `hex 68 65 6C 6C 6F`

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
char *str = "hello";

while (*str) {
    printf("%c %u %x\n", *str, *str, *str);
    str++;
}
```

Comment: i've think something like. there's not a specific function to do that? and i need also to store converted data for make some operation on it. unsigned int is good for storing integer or hex?

Comment: Everything is stored in binary anyway. The difference is how you choose to display them.

Answer (score 3):

In C, A string is just a number of chars in neighbouring memory locations. Two things to do: **(1)** loop over the string, character by character. **(2)** Output each char.

**The solution for (1)** depends on the string's representation (0-terminated or with explicit length?). For 0-terminated strings, use

```
char *c = "a string";
for (char *i = c; *i; ++i) {
   // do something with *i
}
```

Given an explicit length, use

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
   // do something with c[i]
}
```

**The solution for (2)** obviously depends on what you are trying to achieve. To simply output the values, follow [cnicutar's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11590914/1307866) answer and use `printf`. To get a (0-terminated) string containing the representation,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* convert a 0-terminated string to a 0-terminated string of its ascii values,
 * seperated by spaces. The user is responsible to free() the result.
 */
char *to_ascii(const char *inputstring) {

   // allocate the maximum needed to store the ascii represention:
   char *output = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(inputstring) * 4 + 1));
   char *output_end = output;

   if (!output) // allocation failed! omg!
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

   *output_end = '\0';
   for (; *inputstring; ++inputstring) {
      output_end += sprintf(output_end, "%u ", *inputstring);
      //assert(output_end == '\0');
   }

  return output;
}
```

If you need to output an explicit-length string, use `strlen()` or the difference  `(size_t)(output_end-output)`.

Comment: This fails with UB when the input string is empty. Also you've got a stray `output_pos` in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
enum type {decimal, hexa};
char *str = "hello";
char *temp_str = NULL;
temp_str = str;
static enum type index = decimal;
while (*str) {
    if(index == decimal)
     printf("%u\t", *str);
    else
     printf("%x\t",*str);
    str++;
}
printf("\n");
if(index != hexa)
{
   index = hexa;
   str = temp_str;
   main();
}

}
```

hope this will work fine as what u want, and if u want to store it in a uint8_t array, have to just declare an variable for it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 5 years old but my first real program converted strings to ASCII and it was done in a clean and simple way by assigning a variable to getchar() and then calling it in printf() as an integer, all while it's in a loop of course, otherwise getchar() only accepts single characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int i = 0;

    while((i = getchar()) != EOF)
        printf("%d ", i);

    return 0;
}
```

and here's the original version using the for() loop instead because I wanted to see just how small I could make the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    for(int i = 0; (i = getchar()) != EOF; printf("%d ", i); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Receives a string and returns an unsigned integer 
equivalent to its ASCII values summed up */
unsigned int str2int(unsigned char *str){
    int str_len = strlen(str);
    unsigned int str_int = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while(counter <= str_len){
        str_int+= str[counter];
        printf("Acumulator:%d\n", str_int);
        counter++;
    }
    return str_int;
}
```